# Data table column alignment issue . what is best practice to do?

Tags: datatable, datatables

Data table column alignment issue . what is best practice to do? can any of you suggest best way to a[image]lign all column, i want to use 68 column table but its break
 see above image there is column alignment issue

Comment: You really need to elaborate.  What does "*i want to use 68 column table but its break*" mean?

Comment: now added image for issue of alignment